# Echo Array without key using index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Array as shown bellow

```
 Array
    (
        [ifour consultancy 123] => Array
            (
                [Company] => ifour consultancy 123
                [Physical] => B-515, Gopal Palace, Near shiromani complex,
                [address] => test,
             )
    )
```

i am try to print it using

```
echo $array[0]['Company'];
```

and it give me Message:

> Undefined offset: 0
>    instead of showing me ifour consultancy 123

Comment: your index is not "0" but "ifour consultancy 123". use a foreach loop instead.

Comment: is there any way so i can get it using  $array[0]['Company']; and $array["ifour consultancy 123"]['Company']; ?

Comment: @Jkumar Try using `array_values`. See my answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes it is working MonkeyZeus beat you by few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to achieve your goal:

```
// Extract the values of the array and re-use as indexed array
$array = array_values($array);
echo $array[0]['Company'];
```

---

```
// If you want to keep your associative array as well then do this
$array = array_merge($array, array_values($array));
echo $array[0]['Company'];
// OR
echo $array['ifour consultancy 123']['Company'];
```

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of walkthroughs, you need to use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
  print_r($value);
}
```

Or if you want to get `0` or number based indices, you need to use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$numbased = array_values($array);
$numbased[0]["Company"]; // ifour consultancy 123
```